# A container for one key multiple values pairs with simple insertion and lookup in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list a one key multiple values pairs that I want to put in list. The format is this:

```
id: "png", description: "png is good", quality: 100
id: "jpg", description: "jpg is bad", quality: 0
```

The `id` is the key and `description` and `quality` are the two values. I'm going to have about 10 of these to be stored in a list.

I'm looking for a container that are simple to insert and lookup, like a one line insert. I have looked at many examples but couldn't find the right one. The cleanest I've seen is with `QMap` but it can only takes one value. To make it work I'll have to put the values in a struct before putting in `QMap`, but then it'll makes it multiple lines of insertion.

```
struct Prop {
    QString description;
    int quality;

    Prop (QString d, int q)
        : description(d), quality(q)
    {}
};

typedef QMap<QString, Prop> ImageFormat;
QList<ImageFormat> imageFormatList;

imageFormatList.append("png", Prop("png is good", 100)); // this doesn't work
```

Comment: Try surrounding the contents of your insert with curly braces {}.

Comment: @André I got the error `candidate function no viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const QMap<QString, Prop>'`